# Controle de Estoque - "Database locked"

Tags: c#, sqlite

Estou fazendo um controle de estoque em C# e a ideia é que quando o usuário clique em um botão, seja incrementado a quantidade de um registro no DataGridView.

A primeira vez que aperto o botão, ele atualiza perfeitamente. Mas na segunda vez, a aplicação trava e demora um bom tempo pra responder.
Depois quando responde, aparece uma janela escrito "database locked". E em seguida, atualiza o item tudo certo.
Mas não sei como resolver isso.
O código do botão em questão:

```
private void btnPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IDRegistro = 0;
            IDRegistro = Convert.ToInt32(dgvItems.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value); //pega o id do item selecionado no dataGridView
    
            conn = new SQLiteConnection(conexao);
            if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
    
            cmd = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT QTD_ATUAL FROM ESTOQUE WHERE ID = " + IDRegistro, conn);
    
            SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();
            int qtdAtual = Convert.ToInt32(dr["QTD_ATUAL"]);
            qtdAtual++;

            cmd = new SQLiteCommand("UPDATE ESTOQUE SET QTD_ATUAL = @QTD_ATUAL WHERE ID = @ID", conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", IDRegistro);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("QTD_ATUAL", qtdAtual);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    
            MessageBox.Show("Registro atualizado");
            Carregar(); //atualiaza o DataGridView
        }
```

Comment: Deve ter esquecido de fechar a conexão no final do método. Chame o `conn.Open();`

Comment: Não posso garantir que seja isso, mas você esqueceu o `conn.Dispose()`

Comment: Se der exceção também dará problema porque a conexão não será fechada.

Comment: Eu tentei colocar o conn.Dispose() (e tambemo conn.CLose()) no final da funçã - Já que ela abre quando executa - mas ainda assim, não deu certo.
Verifiquei que ele trava no segundo cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que o problema seja que os comandos de read e executenonquery estão entrando em conflito por falta de dispose, segue uma alternativa que possa dar uma saída para esse problema.

```
    private void btnPlus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IDRegistro = 0;
        IDRegistro = Convert.ToInt32(dgvItems.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value); //pega o id do item selecionado no dataGridView

        //utilize o using para fazer o dispose da conexão
        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(conexao))
        {
            if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                conn.Open();
            }

            string query = "SELECT QTD_ATUAL FROM ESTOQUE WHERE ID = " + IDRegistro;
            int qtdAtual = 0; //talvez seja necessário passar 1 para no caso de dados não disponiveis

            //utilize o using para fazer o dispose no final do comando
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(query, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();

                using (SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        qtdAtual = Convert.ToInt32(dr["QTD_ATUAL"]);
                    }
                    qtdAtual++;
                }
            }

            string update = "UPDATE ESTOQUE SET QTD_ATUAL = @QTD_ATUAL WHERE ID = @ID";

            //utilize o using para fazer o dispose no final do comando
            using (SQLiteCommand cmd2 = new SQLiteCommand(update, conn))
            {
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", IDRegistro);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("QTD_ATUAL", qtdAtual);
                cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }


        }
        MessageBox.Show("Registro atualizado");
        Carregar(); //atualiaza o DataGridView
    }
```

Comment: Lucas, muito obrigada! A sua solução deu certo!